# send an Integer >255 over a serial port

Tags: java, serial-port

I'm using serial communication to a micro-controller for a project. 
I created a module with Java which works fine, I thought. Then I found out that it only works for integer values up to 255.
What is a clean and easy method to send bigger values over an serial port? I've never worked with a serial port before. As I would like to write the code for myself in the end, I'm looking for ideas on how to solve this issue.

I'm working with the SerialPort object of the Javax.comm library. The object supports two write methods.

write(int) <- integer to 255
write(Byte[])  <-I think this would be the relevant one.

So my question points towards this problem now -> How do I convert a integer >255 to an Byte[] ?

Thanks

Comment: integer > 255 requires two bytes, so you need to send two bytes. now you get into an ordering problem: do you want big-endian or little-endian?

Comment: you could always treat everything as string data instead and use message formats and delimiters to separate data fields.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think I would have done it with seperators. 
But I just found out, that the values I have to send are not bigger than 200. So a single byte is big enough.

Thank you very much for the ideas, though.